# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $\log |x|$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\log |x|$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. I'm trying to prove that the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $f$, $Mf$, equals $\infty$. That is, for every $x \in \Bbb R^n$,
$$Mf(x) = \sup_{x \in B} \frac{1}{|B|} \int_B |f|  = \infty,$$
where the supremum is taken over all balls $B$ in $\Bbb R^n$ containing $x$ and $|B|$ is the Lebesgue measure of the ball.

The reasoning I tried to use is that for any $x \in \Bbb R^n$ there is a ball $B$ containing $x$ and $0$. Since it contains $0$, $|f| \to \infty$ on $B$, and then $\frac{1}{|B|} \int_B |f|  = \infty$. But I don't know if that's true, do we need that $|f|$ is exactly $\infty$ on $B$ to say that the integral on $B$ is $\infty$? In that case, would we need to define $f(0)=\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may use polar coordinates.

It suffices to consider averages over balls of radii $r>1$.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{m(B_r)}\int_{B_r}\big|\log |x|\big|\,dx&=\frac{n}{r^n}\int^r_0t^{n-1}|\log t|\,dt\\
&=-\frac{n}{r^n}\int^1_0t^{n-1}\log t\,dt+\frac{n}{r^n}\int^r_1 t^{n-1}\log t\,dt
\end{align}

$u=\log t$ ($e^u=t$) gives

$$
\frac{n}{r^n}\int^r_1t^{n-1}\log t\,dt=\frac{n}{r^n}\int^{\log r}_0e^{nu}u\,du\sim\frac{nr^n\log r}{nr^{n-1}}\xrightarrow{r\rightarrow\infty}\infty
$$

It follows that

$$\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{m(B_r)}\int_{B_r}\big|\log|x|\big|\,dx =\infty$$

Comment: Do you know  a reference where I can find that integral formula for polar coordinates? I only found a formula in Corollary 2.51 of Folland's Real Analysis where they use the gamma function: $\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)dx = \sigma(S^{n-1}) \int_0^\infty g(r) r^{n-1}dr$, where $f(x)=g(|x|)$ and $\sigma(S^{n-1})=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$.

Comment: And did it get canceled with $m(B_r)$? Why did you add $n$ as a factor?

Comment: Then is $m(B_r)=\sigma(S^{n-1})r^n/n$?

Comment: @J.Doe: yes, it is!